# Building a Nested Monad

Tags: haskell

I have two own data type as follow:

```
Block a = NoValue | Value a
data GraphAMT a = GraphAMT_ [[Block a]]
```

Now, I want to make instance monads for them like

```
instance Monad Block where
     return a = Value a
     NoValue >>= f = NoValue
     Value a >>= f = f a
     fail _ = NoValue

instance Monad GraphAMT where
     return a = GraphAMT_ [[Value a]]
     GraphAMT_ xs >>= f = ...?
```

I am wondering whether GraphAMT can be a monad? If yes, so how to build it?

Comment: If you have an operation with the type of `(>>=)`, just write it down and check whether it satisfies the monad laws. If you don't have an operation that makes sense for your type that has the type of `(>>=)`, then why do you want to implement the `Monad` class?

Comment: GraphAMT is a type of list of list (or a matrix) [[a]], now I want to add 3 to each element of this matrix, how can I write a monad to do this operation, like : [[NoValue,Value 1],[Value 2,NoValue]] >>= (\x->GraphAMT_ [[x >>= (\x->Value (x+3))]]. So I need 2 monads for this purpose

Comment: You do not need to implement `Monad` to provide an operation that lets you run some function on each element. You could just expose that operation with any old name you like. In this particular case, it might turn out that this operation makes your type a `Functor`, but that's the direction you should think: first make the operation, then check if it's a well-known typeclass (not first pick a typeclass then bang your brains out trying to fit a square peg in a round hole).

Comment: Not trying to fit a square peg in a round hole. But I think people can apply a list [] to a monad, why I cannot apply a list of list [[]] (but in my case `Data GraphAMT a = GraphAMT_ [[a]]) to a monad?  [] can be a monad, why GraphAMT_ [[a]] can't be written like a monad? or I don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
module MatrixOfMatrices where
```

### Applying a function to the elements of your matrix

```
data Block a = NoValue | Value a  deriving Show
data GraphAMT a = GraphAMT_ [[Block a]]  deriving Show
```

Firstly, you don't need Monad to add three to each element, you need `fmap`, so you should make your type an instance of Functor, but it will be easiest to make `Block` a functor first:

```
instance Functor Block where
  fmap f NoValue  = NoValue
  fmap f (Value a) = Value (f a)

instance Functor GraphAMT where
 fmap f (GraphAMT_ xss) = GraphAMT_ . (map . map . fmap $ f) $ xss
```

When

```
testData = GraphAMT_ [[NoValue,Value 2],[Value 56,Value 45,NoValue],[NoValue]]
```

then

```
*MatrixOfMatrices> testData
GraphAMT_ [[NoValue,Value 2],[Value 56,Value 45,NoValue],[NoValue]]
*MatrixOfMatrices> fmap (*10) testData
GraphAMT_ [[NoValue,Value 20],[Value 560,Value 450,NoValue],[NoValue]]
```

as you would hope.

### Making a Matrix into a Monad

Yikes! We need to define `(>>=) :: GraphAMT a -> (a -> GraphAMT b) -> GraphAMT b`. It should take a function that turns elements into a matrix, apply it elementwise, then join the resulting matrix of matrices into one single matrix.

The problem with that is there's no obvious way to make a matrix of matrices into a single matrix the way there is with a list of lists becoming a list. If the elements were all numbers, we could just add them together, making a matrix of maximum size. We can't use solutions like that though, because Monad's aren't able to use any facts about their elements, because they have to work for all types of elements.

There's no definite way to do this - you could put them next to each other by widening each row to accommodate the values of the incoming matrices, or put them underneath each other using transpose. You could start the overlap according to the position in the matrix of matricies each one was at.

Comment: one way to structurally join matrices of matrices is to open up the inner parentheses so to speak. We can have a matrix [[A,B],[C,D]] where A=[[1,2],[3,4]] etc. Where the sizes don't match we could pad the new matrix with NoValue's. That's one possibility. e.g. join [[I,O],[O,I]] becomes I (of bigger size). I'm not sure about the monad laws.